# Randomise while keeping ascending inside the group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have three main tables as follows:

```
SELECT
    Q.QPackID, Q.QGrpID, Q.QID
FROM
    dbo.SV_Q AS Q 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.SV_Q_Pack AS P ON Q.QPackID = P.QPackID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.SV_QGrp AS G ON Q.QGrpID = G.QGrpID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.SV_QM AS M ON Q.QmID = M.QmID
WHERE
    Q.QID IN (SELECT QID FROM MyTable WHERE MyID = 123);
```

| QPackID | QGrpID | QID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 | 7 |
| 3 | 5 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 |
| 4 | 7 | 10 |
| 4 | 8 | 11 |
| 4 | 8 | 12 |

- `QID` belongs to `QGrpID`
- `QGrpID` belongs to `QPackID`

I want to sort this based on:

- `QPackID` to be randomised while keeping fixed within the same `QPackID`
- `QGrp` to be randomised while keeping fixed within the same `QGrpID`
- `QID` to be kept ascending under `QGrpID`

An expected result is like this:

| QPackID | QGrpID | QID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 8 | 11 |
| 4 | 8 | 12 |
| 4 | 7 | 10 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 |
| 3 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 | 7 |
| 3 | 5 | 8 |

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will give you the outcome you want without having to join the table to itself multiple times -

```
DECLARE @X DECIMAL(5, 5);

SELECT @X = RAND();

SELECT Q.QPackID
     , Q.QGrpID
     , Q.QID
FROM dbo.SV_Q AS Q
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SV_Q_Pack AS P
        ON Q.QPackID = P.QPackID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SV_QGrp AS G
        ON Q.QGrpID = G.QGrpID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SV_QM AS M
        ON Q.QmID = M.QmID
WHERE Q.QID IN
      (
          SELECT QID FROM MyTable WHERE MyID = 123
      )
ORDER BY (CAST(Q.QPackID AS DECIMAL(23)) % @X) DESC
       , (CAST(Q.QGrpID AS DECIMAL(23)) % @X) DESC
       , QID ASC;
```

For your query, adjust the `DECIMAL(n)` in the `ORDER BY` clause to your desired size, i.e. if QPackID is a column containing a maximum of 9 digits, use `DECIMAL(9)`.

Example below -
[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AcUG_QpW)

Comment: Thank you so much. Since each ID field are all actually 9 digit integers, I replaced 'DECIMAL(2, 2)' with DECIMAL(11, 2) and works perfect.

Comment: I added your edits to the code. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I really appreciate your kindness.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a random value to each group of Id values.

Here's the basics of how you could do that using *newid()*, here table `t` is your data:

```
select t.* 
from t
cross apply (
    select Max(NewId()) id
    from t t2
    where t2.QPackID = t.QPackID
    group by QPackID 
)qpid
cross apply (
    select Max(NewId()) id
    from t t2
    where t2.QGrpID = t.QGrpID
    group by QGrpID
)qgid
order by qpid.id, qgid.id, t.QID;
```

Here's a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qyHQxpqe) you can check out.

Comment: Thank you so much. The result you offered me is perfect. How can I do this with my existing three tables? I want to do this by dynamic conditions each time.